# Where are Firefox IndexedDB files stored?

Tags: html, firefox, windows-7, firefox4

If I create an IndexedDB in Firefox 4, where are the files stored on my hard drive?  Preferably for Win7, but the path is probably similar across OSes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This post](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.support.firefox/browse_thread/thread/e5066246de644fe1?pli=1) suggests the following location:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application 
Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<xxxx>.default\indexedDB\<databaseid>
```

The `<xxxx>.default` folder is your profile directory, which is where Firefox keeps basically everything.

Comment: Thanks!  That is the WinXP file path.  Here is the Win7 file path: C:\Users\[USERNAME]\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[PROFILE_NAME]\indexedDB

Comment: Chrome on Windows 8.1: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB

Comment: My Firefox 31 keeps it in &AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ [PROFILE_NAME]\storage\persistent\ [ORIGIN]\idb\

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox 105.x (2022), the indexedDB are in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<xxxx>.default\storage\default\<weborigin>\idb
```

The `<xxxx>.default` is the Firefox Profile directory.
The `<weborigin>` is the tag describing the original website which produced the database.

Comment: Is the data encrypted? I cannot see the original value in SQLite tables like object_data.
If it is encrypted, is there a way to edit it through SQLite instead of executing JavaScript code in Firefox DevTools?

Comment: @baptx From my experience, it's not encrypted. If you have a problem to access the data, maybe you should ask a question on SO.