# Where do GM.setValue()s database entries get stored in Firefox/MacOS?

Tags: javascript, macos, firefox, greasemonkey, greasemonkey-4

GreaseMonkey, Firefox, Mac OSX.
I know you can see the keys with GM.listValues() but I cannot find a straightforward answer on Google where the sqlite/file is so that you can read the data somewhere else. I’d like to ideally open the sqlite folder so I can cleanly see the database entries without having to run the GM.listValues() command. I’ve tried looking in my Application Support Folder, about:debugging, about:config… None of the info I’ve seen online is making sense to me.

Comment: Should be in storage/default/moz-extension+++ID in the profile folder where ID is the extension's internal ID as seen in `about:debugging`.

Comment: What makes you think Greasemonkey is using `sqlite`? According to [its source code](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/c0b3b542074b48793fb24023da114cfeb643ec95/src/bg/value-store.js#L19C31-L19C31) it uses [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358704/where-are-firefox-indexeddb-files-stored